# How to split window directly from command line?

Tags: split, vimdiff, multiple-files, linux, command-line-window

I'm using Ubuntu system. I have files: A.txt, B.txt, C.txt

I can split window in the following way:

```
vim A.txt
:vs B.txt    // after entering into vim
:vs C.txt
```

Is there any way to achieve the same effect using command line? like vim -option A.txt B.txt C.txt ?

```
vim A.txt B.txt    doesn't work, it doesn't show the files simultaneously
vimdiff *.txt     works, but I really don't need the difference shown
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vim's `-o` and `-O` options will open the files while splitting them horizontally or vertically respectively.

Taken from Vim's help page `:help -o` and `:help -O`:

```
                            *-o*
-o[N]       Open N windows, split horizontally.  If [N] is not given,
        one window is opened for every file given as argument.  If
        there is not enough room, only the first few files get a
        window.  If there are more windows than arguments, the last
        few windows will be editing an empty file.
        {not in Vi}

                            *-O*
-O[N]       Open N windows, split vertically.  Otherwise it's like -o.
        If both the -o and the -O option are given, the last one on
        the command line determines how the windows will be split.
        {not in Vi}
```

Example:

1. `vim -o A.txt B.txt C.txt` will open three horizontal splits for each file.
2. `vim -O A.txt B.txt C.txt` will open three vertical splits for each file

Comment: Related: Also see Vim's `-p` option to open each file in different tab pages.

Comment: BTW, how do you switch among tabs when using `-p` option? I tried `ctrl`+`PageDown`, `ctrl`+`tab` and `ctrl`+`w`. No one works.

Comment: @user3813057 you can use the tab navigation commands. For example `:help gt` and `:help gT`